# asp.net hover menu item

Tags: asp.net, menu, hover, menuitem

When I hover on a static menu item that has a dynamic menu, the hover styles are in effect but once I start navigating the dynamic menu the static menu item goes back to the non-hover styles. Does anyone know how to make them stick until I stop ''using' that menu? I tried the 'selected' static menu item styles but that doesn't work - if I use them, even when I stop navigating the menu the last selected static menu item will display the selected style - after using the menu I want the styles to revert to the normal styles....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hover is basically an encapsulation of mouseover and mouseout event and it is tied to one element. For instance if you have an implemented a menu as an ordered list and have implemented hover for list item then each and every element will have mouseover and mouseout event associated with it. In your case hover cannot be used. I think it would be better to use custom logic.

HTH